# Should we name and shame users with lots of offensive comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, offensive

I won't name names and I don't want to either :) But I have found myself flagging lots of comments from one user.  "Your stupid", "Go away", etc etc

It looks like the only thing that happens is those comments might get deleted?  Should something else happen if you have > n flagged comments? An anti-badge lol?

Comment: naming and shaming is a really nasty thing to do

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're doing exactly the correct thing by flagging these comments as offensive.

Moderators get notified when a user is repeatedly posting offensive and abusive comments. By flagging, you allow mods to handle this issue in a constructive, non-public-shaming way. Many times this works. Furthermore, moderators have more tools to handle such users' actions, including the ability to delete comments, suspend (as needed) and even speak privately with a user in a chatroom or through the behavior notification tools.

So, short version: **no, don't publicly shame users**. Let the moderators handle it by flagging.

Comment: Cool - I don't want to name names :)

Answer (score 17):

Was going to leave this as a comment, but it's more of a secondary answer.

I would only bring it up here if you're flagging multiple times and not getting any results, e.g. the behavior is continuing without a moderator intervening. And even then I would only bring it up as a general question ...

> "why are my repeated offensive comment flags not resulting in action?"

... *never* by naming specific users.

We like to address *behaviors* here, not specific users. It's more useful to more people that way, and it's more optimistic: people's behaviors can change. Addressing the behavior decouples it from the person and removes any blame or stigma that might work against positive change in behavior.

Comment: You're just here for the hats, aren't you?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Of course he is. Why do you think everyone's on meta today?

Comment: @Manishearth: I certainly can't fault it. It's why my own to-do list has been forgotten for the past hour and half.

Comment: There are hats here too? Excellent!